# Анимация css, js

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation, scss

Можно как-то воссоздать такую же анимацию иконок снизу (telegram) как на этом сайте - https://rocketboys.io/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте инструменты разработчика и наведите на иконку, там все есть:

```css
section {
  background-color: #242424;
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:hover {
  padding-top: 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: #78d246;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 10rem #78d246 !important;
  transition: .2s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <a href="https://t.me/RocketBoys0fficial" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram">i</i>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```